# Problema al imprimir lista

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un cajero automático en python, lo estaba probando y resulta que al imprimir con `print()` a la lista `entregado[]` me da el siguiente error:

```
File "class.py", line 10, in __repr__
    return "<__main__.Billete: valor = " + int(self.valor)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Código:

```
import math


class Billete():
    def __init__(self, valor, cantidad):
        self.valor = valor
        self.cantidad = cantidad

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<__main__.Billete: valor = " + 
        int(self.valor)+ "; cantidad = " + int(self.cantidad) + ";>"


papeles = 0
dinero = 300
entregado = []
caja = []
caja.append(Billete(500, 5))
caja.append(Billete(200, 6))
caja.append(Billete(100, 4))


def entregarDinero():
    global caja
    global dinero
    global entregado
    for bi in caja:
        if (dinero > 0):
            div = math.floor(dinero / bi.valor)
        if (div > bi.cantidad):
            papeles = bi.cantidad
        else:
            papeles = div
     entregado.append(Billete(bi.valor, papeles))
     dinero = dinero - (bi.valor * papeles)


entregarDinero()
print(str(entregado[:]))
```

Comment: Estás intentando concatenar una cadena con un entero, de ahí el error. Te recomiendo usar f-strings si estás con Python 3.6+, haciendo `return f"<__main__.Billete: valor = {self.valor}; cantidad = {self.cantidad};>"`. Si estás con una versión más antigua, usa `str.format()` así: `return "<__main__.Billete: valor = {}; cantidad = {};>".format(self.valor, self.cantidad)`

Comment: Ya puestos, por cierto, cambiaría el formato de lo que retornas en`__repr__` a algo más agradable de leer, como: `return f"Billete(valor={self.valor}, cantidad={self.cantidad})"`, que además sigue la norma de que la representación dada por `repr()` debería ser sintaxis python válida para crear ese objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que pasa es que estas convirtiendo un `int` a `int`, asi que por eso te da el error. Deberías intentar con esto:

```
import math


class Billete():
    def __init__(self, valor, cantidad):
        self.valor = valor
        self.cantidad = cantidad

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<__main__.Billete: valor = " + 
        str(self.valor)+ "; cantidad = " + str(self.cantidad) + ";>"


papeles = 0
dinero = 300
entregado = []
caja = []
caja.append(Billete(500, 5))
caja.append(Billete(200, 6))
caja.append(Billete(100, 4))


def entregarDinero():
    global caja
    global dinero
    global entregado
    for bi in caja:
        if (dinero > 0):
            div = math.floor(dinero / bi.valor)
        if (div > bi.cantidad):
            papeles = bi.cantidad
        else:
            papeles = div
     entregado.append(Billete(bi.valor, papeles))
     dinero = dinero - (bi.valor * papeles)


entregarDinero()
print(str(entregado[:]))
```

Comment: wow, muchas gracias Angel me ayudaste muchísmo, un abrazo

Comment: De nada. Suerte en tu proyecto :D